# AngularJS array filtering according to another array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, binding, watch

Suppose you have an array of objects:

```
   data = [{id:1, name="A"}, {id:2, name="B"}, {id:3, name="C"}, ....]
```

And you have two arrays:

```
selectedData = [{id:1, name="A"}, {id:3, name="C"}]
```

and

```
selectedDataIds = [1,3]
```

I want these two arrays are bound each other.

e.g. when

```
selectedDataIds = [1]
```

then

```
selectedData = [{id:1, name="A"}]
```

and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could put both of the arrays into a service and then control the update of the arrays through method calls. Check out my plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UP165Z35xF5RTm57TZgB?p=preview). It's just a cursory attempt however I think that you could use it as a starting point.